# WCF service throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

i was trying to create basic WCF service and host it on a console application.

Here's my code of WCF project.

*ISampleService.cs*

```
using System.ServiceModel;  

namespace MultipleSeviceContractAppl  
{  
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "ISampleService" in both code and config file together.  
    [ServiceContract]  
    public interface ISampleService  
    {  
        [OperationContract]  
        string DoWork();  
    }  
}
```

*SampleService.cs*

```
namespace MultipleSeviceContractAppl  
{  
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "SampleService" in both code and config file together.  
    public class SampleService : ISampleService  
    {  
        public string DoWork()  
        {  
            return "Message from WCFservice";  
        }  
    }  
}
```

*App.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<configuration>  
  <system.serviceModel>  

    <behaviors>  
      <serviceBehaviors>  
        <behavior name="mexBehaviour">  
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>  
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />  
        </behavior>  
      </serviceBehaviors>  
    </behaviors>

    <services>  
      <service name="MultipleSeviceContractAppl.SampleService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">  
        <endpoint address="SampleService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="MultipleSeviceContractAppl.ISampleService">  
        </endpoint>  
        <host>  
          <baseAddresses>  
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/"/>  <!--For metadata exchange-->
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8737/" />  <!--Endpoint, netTCP binding, For data exchange-->
          </baseAddresses>  
        </host>  
      </service>  
    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>  
</configuration>
```

*WCF Hosting on console appl - Program.cs*

```
using System;  
using System.ServiceModel;  
namespace ConsumeWCFApplicationAppl  
{  
    class Program  
    {  
        static void Main()  
        {  
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MultipleSeviceContractAppl.SampleService)))  
            {  
                host.Open();  
                Console.WriteLine("Host started @" + DateTime.Now.ToString());  
                Console.ReadKey();  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

in console application at line **host.Open();**, following exception was thrown.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll Additional information: Service
>   'MultipleSeviceContractAppl.SampleService' has zero application
>   (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration
>   file was found for your application, or because no service element
>   matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or
>   because no endpoints were defined in the service element. Help me to
>   figure out my mistake. Thanks

Comment: Try specifying the base addresses in the `ServiceHost` constructor:  `ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MultipleServiceContractApp1.SapmleService), new Uri[] { "http://localhost:8733/", "net.tcp://localhost:8737/" });`  Also, you may need to run with elevated priveleges to register the net.tcp address.

Comment: Adding above line throws a new error Severity _Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Uri'_

Comment: The problem with your application is that ,its not able to find your app.config file.Delete it and add it once again or create a new solution ,some problem with detecting app.config.

Comment: @LearnAvid - try `ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MultipleServiceContractApp1.SapmleService), new Uri[] { new Uri("http://localhost:8733/"), new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8737/") });`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replicate the config in your console app and add reference to DLL of the service model assemblies to this project...

```
<behaviors>  
  <serviceBehaviors>  
    <behavior name="mexBehaviour">  
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>  
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />  
    </behavior>  
  </serviceBehaviors>  
</behaviors>

<services>  
  <service name="MultipleSeviceContractAppl.SampleService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">  
    <endpoint address="SampleService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="MultipleSeviceContractAppl.ISampleService">  
    </endpoint>  
    <host>  
      <baseAddresses>  
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/"/>  <!--For metadata exchange-->
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8737/" />  <!--Endpoint, netTCP binding, For data exchange-->
      </baseAddresses>  
    </host>  
  </service>  
</services>
```

Comment: I think we shouldn't add app.config in any host application.

Comment: Why would you not add an app.config to the host application?  WCF runs off the config (unless you programatically configure it).

Comment: my friend as I said, you  must replicate your system model config to the console host app, unless you did it programmatically in c# code. did you try to see that i am correct??

Comment: Thanks @Jailson Evora, Tim for your responses. I updated console application's (Host appl) app.config with above configuration. it works !!